# Wasabi automatically restart docker container

Tags: java, docker, intuit-wasabi

*I've installed Wasabi as instructed here: https://github.com/intuit/wasabi*

My Wasabi is running on Google Cloud, Ubuntu 16.04.

The problem is that after some time, Cassandra is crashing and not restarting automatically.

When I go to `/api/v1/ping`, I get this:

```
{"componentHealths":[{"componentName":"Experiments Cassandra","healthy":false,"detailedMessage":"PoolTimeoutException: [host=172.18.0.2(172.18.0.2):9160, latency=20000(20000), attempts=1]Timed out waiting for connection"},{"componentName":"MySql","healthy":true}],"version":"wasabi-api-1.0.20161107232436-SNAPSHOT-development-${scmBranch}-${buildNumber}-201701111439"}
```

Is it possible to restart container automatically when it crashes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `restart` flag. From `man docker run`:

```
--restart="no"
        Restart policy to apply when a container exits (no,
        on-failure[:max-retry], always, unless-stopped).
```

You can try it creating a container with `--restart=always`, and then later kill that container from the host (you can use something like `docker inspect --format '{{.State.Pid}}' CONTAINER_NAME` to find the pid of the container). It should restart right after the kill.

Also note that if you use docker to stop/kill the container (ex `docker kill`) it will not be restarted.

Comment: Thanks! I've made the change, but running `docker inspect --format '{{.State.Pid}}' wasabi-cassandra` returns `4189` and `docker ps` says it's up for 10min, shouldn't the count start from 0 after killing?

Comment: I think it will not restart the time. You can run again the inspector command  and the given PID should be different

Comment: Ran `docker inspect --format '{{.State.Pid}}' wasabi-cassandra` got `4189`, waited for a while, ran `docker inspect --format '{{.State.Pid}}' wasabi-cassandra` again and still got `4189`, also `docker inspect -f "{{ .RestartCount }}" wasabi-cassandra` is 0

Comment: Mmm interesting... Do your servicre logs anything at startup time that can be used to check the container has restarted?

Comment: yes, and nothing is logged on `docker inspect --format '{{.State.Pid}}' wasabi-cassandra`

Comment: You must be doing something wrong, or using an older docker verison. I have tried those steps and both the pid changes and uptime is also right. Are you sure you killed the process (`sudo kill -9 PID`)?

Comment: Okay, so I just had to rebuild my containers after making the changes. Now it working perfectly fine, thanks!